# Print C# returned result on an HTML file

Tags: c#, html, fileserver

For homework I have to create a C# application that allows you to browse the local filesystem in order to upload files to a server and navigate the filesystem of the local computer and the server

I would need help with not so much navigating the filesystem, which I have already implemented like this:

```
foreach(string file in ArrayFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

But, how can I, instead of printing these results on the console, print them on html?

And how could I do to make this result clickable (like by putting for each clickable object an association with the execution of a method and a string of where the path should point to)?

Thanks for your answers:)

Comment: "How to turn a console app into a web application" is a tad broad. Have you tried creating a new MVC application and going from there? Or do you mean you want to generate one HTML file that contains all files in a directory?

Comment: The fact is I have to do it in a certain way, creating a console app and running it con localhost

Comment: Again, "how to turn a console application into a web application" is too broad of a question here. Just start a new .NET Core MVC app, it's also hosted in a console app that runs on localhost.

Comment: You are definitively right, but instead of creating a MVC app (which I never heard of but surely I'll look it up) my teacher wants me to use using System.Net
and System.Net.Sockets libs, and theoretically they should be enough, and simply I should print the result of this foreach on an html, and then if possible make them clickable, but that will come later.

Comment: So they want you to implement an HTTP server using sockets?

Comment: Exactly, we have to create this sort of server as a project on sockets

Comment: Implementing HTTP is not trivial. A subset of the protocol that responds _something_ is, but it won't be compliant. Look at F12 in your browser to see what's sent and received, plenty of examples online as well.